# Django - form.is_valid always returning true

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

And the following view:

```
def contact(request):
    from forms import ContactForm
    from django.contrib import messages

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid:
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you for your feedback!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the fields in red below.')

    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    t = loader.get_template('contact.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'ContactForm': form,
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I'm using Django 1.4, and according to the documentation the fields are by default required so I don't need to add `required=True` for each field.

For some reason, `form.is_valid` is always true. The `Thank you for your feedback!` message always appears when I submit the form even though `form.name/email/message.errors` is populated with errors! I have also tried explicitly setting `required=True` for each field, however it made no difference.

This is how I'm showing messages in `contact.html`:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if form.is_valid:
```

to

```
if form.is_valid():
```

Comment: That moment when you realize you have spent hours debugging something that trivial! Thanks!